# I need example about Ext.draw.engine.ImageExporter

Tags: extjs4.1

I want to export Ext Chart using type SVG. But i dont understand it.
Could you give me a example about Ext.draw.engine.ImageExporter (Ext 4.1)

Thank for helping
Nguyen

Answer (score 0):

A working example that uses the `ImageExporter`:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/charts/Area.html

Comment: Thank for quick reply. So If I want to export this chart to excel. Could i do it ? Please help me